# FFMPEG: Can't get audio stream from RTSP Camera IP: V380 Pro

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, camera, rtsp

This is the case:

https://www.banggood.com/10LED-5X-Zoom-HD-2MP-IP-Security-Camera-WiFi-Wireless-1080P-Outdoor-PTZ-Waterproof-Night-Vision-ONVIF-p-1527199.html?rmmds=category&ID=47184&cur_warehouse=CN

It's called V380 Pro probably on shenzen build.

Here you can find some SDK if that help in anything: https://github.com/brusdev/V380-SDK

I'm using this command to record it via ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.25:554/live/ch00_1 -c copy -acodec copy -map 0 -strict experimental -strftime 1 -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 output_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

Everything works fine except that the audio doesnt recording but of course this camera has an audio output (as the input with microphone)

Tried ffprobe to recognize audio stream but there is none. Looks like ffmpeg doesnt see it or it's somehow combined with video output?

And here is ffprobe from this same camera but recorded via their windows app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaPUN.png

As you can see now there is some audio output stream.